# Image_Processing using C# in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, image-processing

I have coded my algorithms in Visual C# 2010 but i have not been able to find a way to use the same code in another computer that has only ubuntu 12.04. Could you tell me how to use the same code without having to rewrite it again in ubuntu or otherwise the least painful method to get it running in ubuntu?

Comment: think MONO project will solve the problem for 2008 but will it work for 2010 also?

Comment: You are going to have to try it out.